# Predicting memory consumption of java components

Tags: java, memory-consumption

I am currently working on an event driven System with multiple components running. Recently , I  have received an urgent  requirement to identify the memory consumption of java components running , so that we can give a brief idea of memory requirements before it is getting deployed on UAT/customer production environments.

Do we have any API using which Deep retained size can be calculated or a formula can be provided using which memory requirements can be computed.

Any ideas on this will surely help.

I have seen some API's ( java instrumentation Api) using which Shallow size can be calculated , but this will not suffice my need.
I also found java Assist using which java byte code can be modified at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

To identify the memory consumption of a java aplication, you can use a profiler. 
In jdk 6 or greater you can find jvisualvm (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jvisualvm.html).

With jvisualvm, you can attach to a java process and, in sampler tab, you can see the memory consumed grouped by class type.
There are even other powerful profilers ([JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) is one of them)

Answer (score 0):

Enable garbage collection logging and analyze the log. As a bonus you will also be able to identify (and fix) aberrant behaviour.

To turn on gc logging, use the following flags:

> -verbose:gc
>   -XX:+PrintGCDetails
>   -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
>   -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
>   -XX:+PrintGCCause
>   -Xloggc:/gc-%t.log

This log file can then be handled in a number of tools like Censum from JClarity or uploaded to https://gceasy.io/ for easy analysis. Note that you will see the memory consumption as a whole for the app, not a breakdown. For that you will have to use something like VisualVM mentioned above.

Comment: Hi Erik, i want to analyse the consumption at the startup itself . I am looking out for something using which i can modify the bytecode and derive out the deep  retained size of objects. Using this i want to create some formula to analyse the consumption done by a particular component.

Comment: That is not apparent from reading your original submission. Please update it to include the detail you gave in your comment. Note tho' that the memory consumption at startup do not equal the memory consumption once the app has reached some sort of steady state. That should be more important than the startup behaviour unless it's really aberrant.